# Git push force issue - Unable to force local changes on top of remote

Tags: git, heroku, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I checkout to a 'previous' commit on master and made changes to it locally. Then I wanted my local changes to override everything that is on master and become the head. To do this I typed in following:

```
 git push origin master --force
```

So now in 'sourcetree' my repo looks like this:
[image]

Basically I want the "cherry pick ..." to be the head/master and push that to heroku

If I look at bitbucket the origin/master is still the old one. Also pushing to heroku says

```
=> git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Everything up-to-date
```

How do I get my changes at the top of all the changes in the branch

Comment: The commit that is called 'cherry pick', have you cherry-picked it into your master branch?

Comment: No I cherry picked it on a previous branch .. "shorten meta desc" branch. I want to throw off anything after that and push my local changes on top of "shorten meta desc" branch and make it Head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would suggest you to do would be to `git reset --hard {previous commit}` on your master branch and then cherry pick the commits you want into master. Then you can do `git push --force`  to change your HEAD.

When you do checkout to a previous commit you are creating a temp branch.

```
git checkout {previous commit}
```

Comment: I am relatively new to Git. What do you mean by "git reset --hard {previous commit} on your master" should I just do git reset --hard {shorten_meta_SHA} and then apply the changes ? One more problem is  I have some Rails assets issues in the newer commits which I cant figure out. So I want to just start on a prev working branch/commit , make code changes and call it the new latest working code

Comment: You should do `git checkout master` this way you will be on the master branch. Then you would do `git reset --hard commit_hash` this will put your HEAD on the commit_hash that you provide. Then after you make your changes and commit your changes, you would do `git push --force` to force your commit onto remote, because remote has a different history than you, it would not accept your commits with a normal push.

Comment: Thanks!. It seem to almost work except the force push which gives me error : "remote: permission denied to force push branch master"

Comment: That's a permission from your git administrator :). An alternative would be to revert the commits you have by `git revert commit_id` this will create new commits which are reverting these changes. and the have your new commits and then push. This way you can do normal push as the history won't be changed

Comment: Thanks I changed the permissions on my bitbucket and push --force worked fine